# What is minimum age for relations for a boy when passive

Tags: halacha, sexuality

I understand that someone to be given the death penalty for relations with a girl she needs to be at least 3 years old

But how about with a boy.
What is the minimum age the boy needs to be for someone to be able to get the death penalty for relations with him (I understand that if the boy is active it is 9)
But what is the age when the boy is passive (being penetrated)

Sources please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rambam, Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Issurei Biah 1:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5101.htm)

> ואם היה קטן בן תשע שנים ויום אחד ומעלה--זה שבא עליו או הביאו על עצמו, נסקל; והקטן, פטור.  ואם היה הזכור בן תשע או פחות, שניהן פטורין; וראוי לבית דין להכות הגדול מכת מרדות, לפי ששכב עם זכור, ואף על פי שהוא פחות מבן תשע

Death penalty is only if the boy is at least nine years old, **in either position**.

However, the court ought to administer lashes in cases where the boy is younger than nine.